# How to pass a date parameter into a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a stored procedure for booking rooms that are not in the `tblBooking` table for the date which is passing in as a parameter.

`Pdate` is of type `varchar`

When I try to run this stored procedure with the command:

```
usr_sp_Search_Room_by_City_Date '','8','','DEC 13 2014'
```

It is throws this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
>   Incorrect syntax near '%D%'.

Here is my procedure:

```
ALTER procedure usr_sp_Search_Room_by_City_Date 
    @RoomName varchar(100),
    @CityId int = 0,
    @LandMark varchar(100),
    @BookingDate varchar
as
begin
   Declare @Query as varchar(max)

   set @Query = 'Select * from tblUser tblusr 
                 join tblUserLogIn tblusrL on tblusr.UserId = tblusrL.UserId
                 join tblRoom tblP on tblP.RoomId = tblusr.UserId 
                 join tblImage tblImg on tblImg.RoomId = tblusr.UserId 
                 join tblCountry on tblP.RoomCountryId = tblCountry.CntryId 
                 join tblState on tblState.StateId = tblP.RoomStateId
                 join tblCity on tblCity.CityId = tblP.RoomCityId 
                 join tblRoomType on tblRoomType.RoomTypeId = tblP.RoomTypeId
                 where ''true''=tblImg.IsProfileImage and ''true''=tblusrL.Isconfirmed'

   if(@BookingDate != ' ')
      set @Query=@Query+'and tblP.RoomId not in (Select RoomId from tblBookings 

   where Pdate like ''%'+CAST(@BookingDate AS VARCHAR)+'%'''

   exec(@Query)

end
```

Comment: First I suggest you rewrite your query to not use dynamic SQL. There is no need for it and as you are discovering, it is error prone.

Comment: DateTime datatype will do all your work with Convert function that is designed for datetime types.

Comment: in sp you can use getdate()

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters (`@BookingDate`) that you use - otherwise, you end up with a parameter of **exactly 1 character length** - therefore, your date you're trying to pass in is truncated to just `D` ....

Answer (score 2):

If you printed out the query, you would probably find something like this:

```
where 'true'=tblImg.IsProfileImage and 'true'=tblusrL.Isconfirmedand tblP.RoomId not in (Select RoomId from tblBookings
```

Notice that the `where` statement runs into the `and`, because you have no spacer.

You don't intend for the comparison to be to `'%D%'`, but that is not a syntax error.  This is cause because you have omitted lengths on `varchar()` declarations.

Here are my recommendations:

- Always use length with `varchar()`.
- If you want to pass a date into a stored procedure, use a date variable, not a `varchar()`.
- Don't use `like` with dates.
- Debug this code by printing out `@Query` to see what is really being generated.

Answer (score 0):

The source of the actual error is due to you needing a final right parenthesis at the end of:

```
AS VARCHAR)+'%'')'
```

Also, you need a space at the beginning of the `set @Query=@Query+'and` statement. Currently the SQL will render as (partially):

```
'true'=tblusrL.Isconfirmedand tblP.RoomId not
```

Even better, you don't even need the CAST as the datatype is already `VARCHAR`, so the SET controlled by the IF should be:

```
SET @Query = @Query + ' AND tblP.RoomId not in (Select RoomId from tblBookings 
  where Pdate like ''%'+ @BookingDate + '%'')';
```

Always specify a size for variable length datatypes. The `@BookingDate` input parameter and `CAST(@BookingDate AS VARCHAR)` (which again, should be removed anyway) should both specify `VARCHAR(20)`. The default size for VARCHAR / NVARCHAR / etc, in *some* situations, is 1. In other situations it is 30. In either case, do not rely upon defaults.

General notes:

- What does the actual data in the `Pdate` field look like? Just wondering why you are using `LIKE` instead of `=` for the test.
- You should probably use the `BIT` datatype for `IsProfileImage` and `Isconfirmed`, or at least `TINYINT`. Either one would be incredibly more efficient than a string field.

Answer (score 0):

Is not about the date.

This is the output query from your dynamics query

```
Select * from tblUser tblusr 
join tblUserLogIn tblusrL on tblusr.UserId=tblusrL.UserId
join tblRoom tblP on tblP.RoomId=tblusr.UserId join tblImage tblImg 
on tblImg.RoomId=tblusr.UserId 
join tblCountry on tblP.RoomCountryId=tblCountry.CntryId join tblState 
on tblState.StateId=tblP.RoomStateId
join tblCity on tblCity.CityId=tblP.RoomCityId join tblRoomType 
on tblRoomType.RoomTypeId=tblP.RoomTypeId
where 'true'=tblImg.IsProfileImage and 'true'=tblusrL.Isconfirmedand tblP.RoomId not in (Select RoomId from tblBookings 

where Pdate like '%0%'
```

You miss the ")" at the end.

```
where Pdate like ''%'+CAST(@BookingDate AS VARCHAR)+'%'')'
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you pass a date parameter?  First, specify the datatype as date, not varchar.

Second, you don't need dynamic sql.  You can use a case construct for your conditional logic.  Specifically, this:

```
if(@BookingDate!=' ')
set @Query=@Query+'and tblP.RoomId not in (Select RoomId from tblBookings 
where Pdate like ''%'+CAST(@BookingDate AS VARCHAR)+'%'''
```

can be something like this.

```
where @BookingDate is null
or 
(
@BookingDate is not null
and 
tblP.RoomId not in 
(Select RoomId from tblBookings 
where Pdate = @BookingDate)
)
```